# TeX code of equations from IEEEXplore

Tags: equations, amsmath

Recently IEEE gives the TeX code for most of equations in the HTML full text view of the papers. This is very interesting for me that I can skip rewriting some long equations and use TeX code from the website. However, I cannot usually compile the equations properly.

Here is a MWE from equation (A1) in [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/icp.jsp?arnumber=6514819) (paper is freely open to anyone through open access model).

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    $$D_{E}\propto\left\{\matrix{\left[(1-A)\cos (kh\sin\theta)-2B\cos\beta\right]^{2}    
    \hfill\cr+\left[(1+A)\sin (kh\sin\theta)+2B\sin\beta\right]^{2}\hfill}\right\}
    \times\sin^{2}\theta\eqno{\hbox{(A3)}}$$

    \end{document}
```

Should I use some specific packages (like amsmath), or use some compilers (like XeTeX)???

Comment: This equation runs with pdfLaTeX without any packages, just with the article class. Perhaps post a complete MWE and the error message you get. Btw. `$$` is a bad syntax with LaTeX. better change to \\[...\\] if you don't use just TeX.

Comment: Thanks. yes, you are right, with `article` and without any package, it is fine. But if I add some packages it does not work. Why this is happening?

Comment: As I said, show a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). We cannot guess, what is meant by "some" packages and "does not work" without error message and example code.

Answer (score 3):

This code is Plain TeX style. It will possibly run on LaTeX, but `\matrix` will give an error if `amsmath` is loaded.

Some changes are needed for using the code in LaTeX (I assume also `amsmath`):

```
\begin{equation}
D_{E}\propto
  \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
  &(1-A)\cos(kh\sin\theta)-2B\cos\beta]^{2}\\
  &\quad{}+[(1+A)\sin(kh\sin\theta)+2B\sin\beta]^{2}
  \end{aligned}
  \right\}
  \times\sin^{2}\theta
\tag{A3}
\end{equation}
```

This throws away all foreign commands such as `\matrix` and `\cr`; also the inner `\left` and `\right` have been removed (they are wrong). For the alignment it's better to use `aligned`. Of course `\eqno` must never be used in LaTeX; I used `\tag{A3}` here, but probably this should be left to the automatic numbering.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered **Plain package** which can be used to handle *Plain TeX* codes inside normal LaTeX documents. This allows packages like `amsmath`, `pgfplots`, etc  be loaded in the same documents. Also, one does not need to stick to `article` documentclass.

You need to put your plain TeX code inside a plain environment.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{plain}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{plain}
$$D_{E}\propto\left\{\matrix{\left[(1-A)\cos (kh\sin\theta)-2B\cos\beta\right]^{2}    
\hfill\cr+\left[(1+A)\sin (kh\sin\theta)+2B\sin\beta\right]^{2}\hfill}\right\}
\times\sin^{2}\theta\eqno{\hbox{(A3)}}$$
\end{plain}

\begin{align}
E = m c^2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```